# How can I say this?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is my sentence correct?
"When you come to my house, you first have to take the train, get out of it at the 3° station, and then take the bus n°60. My house is in front of the supermarket."

"你来我家的时候, 你要坐火车, zài3 火车站下车, 然后你换60路公共汽车. 我家zài超市前边."

I'm sorry for "zài", I can't write it with my phone... I don't know why...

Comment: By "3° station" do you mean "3rd stop"?

Comment: Yes exactly, is it ok??

Comment: @Chiara Nobody uses that in China... Say 第三个站.

Comment: @Chiara you can say 在第三站下车.

Comment: Please come up with a better heading than "How can I say this?", it doesn't ehm say anything about you question.

Answer (score 1):

When you come to my house,
你来我房子的时候，
you first have to take the train, 
首先要坐火车，
get out of it at the 3° station, 
在第三个站下，
and then take the bus n°60.
然后坐 N60 路。
My house is in front of the supermarket.
我的房子在超市的前面。

Comment: Ok, just a thing: in your last sentence you have put 的 and 面 instead of 边. Is " 的" necessary? Do 面 and 边 have a different meaning and when should I prefer one instead of the other?

Comment: In this case, you can replace 面 with 边. 前面, 前边, 左面, 左边. The different is 面 means face to, 边 means aside.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more like English translation, here it is: (The ultimate translation is not necessarily doing it literally, that was what I learned from translation graduate school :)

"你来我家的时候, 你要坐火车, 在第三站下车, 然后你换60路公共汽车. 我家就在超市前边."

Before you come to my house, you'll need to take the train, then transfer to #60 bus at 3rd stop. My house is in front of the supermarket.

Comment: So, in your opinion, all my sentences are correct exept the third one? Do i have to put "de" as Mikespook suggested before the last word?

Comment: With or without the "de" would both work.

Comment: Great thank you very much! Last question, are you native speaker?

Comment: Yes I'm a native speaker for more than 30 years! :)